# Best practice for including a JavaScript on certain WordPress pages

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I need to include a JavaScript file on certain specific pages of my WordPress site. The way I'm handling in currently is that I'm parenting all the pages to a particular parent page, and including the JavaScript on pages that have the specified parent.

This works, but it seems a little clunky. Is there a better way to include a JavaScript file on an essentially arbitrary set of pages?

Here's what I'm using currently, to give you an idea of what I'm looking for:

```
function include_crm_wp_funcs(){
  global $post;
  if( get_the_title($post->post_parent) == 'My Parent Page' ){
    require_once 'myJavaScript.js';
  }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','include_crm_wp_funcs');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function include_crm_wp_funcs(){
  global $post;
  if( get_the_title($post->post_parent) == 'My Parent Page' ){
     wp_register_script( 'js_name', get_template_directory_uri() . 'PATH TO YOUR JS FILE' );
     wp_enqueue_script( 'js_name' );
  }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','include_crm_wp_funcs');
```

You need to put the javascript file in your theme directory and call it using [wp_register_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

Comment: Oops, thanks, I forget about wp_register/enqueue_script. What I'm looking for, though, is an alternative to using the page parent. What other ways are there of setting up a particular group of pages?